# GoogleBigQuery save as table

Tags: google-bigquery

I ran this query with Google BigQuery:

```
SELECT repo.id, count(*) as count FROM (
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([githubarchive:day.events_], 
    TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01'), 
    TIMESTAMP('2015-06-01')
  )) 
WHERE type = 'ForkEvent' group by repo.id
```

After I see the results, I want to save results as `CSV` or `JSON`. But GoogleBigQuery asks me to save as table. There are three parameters listed.
When I click the second drop down list `Destination dataset`, nothing shows up. I cannot make any selection. Therefore, I cannot save results successfully.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Reloading the UI and simply making sure your browser doesn't block any javascript loaded on the page should do it. If you have AdBlock or similar make sure it's disabled for the BigQuery UI.

Other than this, you can directly write the results of the query to a table in query mode, using the Destination Table option that is available under Show Options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there may be no datasets in the project you're trying to save the table in.  First, you should [create a dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-web-ui#managedatasets) in your project, and then you should be able to use the dialog you're talking about to save to a table in your newly-created dataset.

As Pentium10 notes, you can also select a destination table in the query options in order to directly save to a table, but that will also require you to have a dataset in which to save the table.