# Save as table results from sql

Tags: google-bigquery

I run an SQL query in google big query console successfully.

I try to download as csv the results but I receive the message that I have first save as table. I press this button but I receive this error:

```
Access Denied: Dataset project-201220:testtable: The user myemail@gmail.com does not have bigquery.tables.create permission for dataset project-201220:testtable.
```

Is there anything I can make in the configuration?

Also if I use [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33718820/9492143) the error is this:

```
Query Failed
Error: Access Denied: Dataset project-201220:stackoverflow: The user myemail@gmail.com does not have bigquery.tables.create permission for dataset project-201220:stackoverflow.
```

Comment: message is clear! ask the owner of that dataset to give you proper permissions

Comment: Oh. are you actually trying to save into public dataset!? no - it is not going to work! you should use your dataset for this. does it make sense?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I try this dataset https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow. Is there any way to fork the public dataset?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Here my steps. I press the button "GO TO STACK OVERFLOW DATASET" I go to users table and go to "Query table" tab. I run this query `SELECT id,reputation FROM [bigquery-public-data:stackoverflow.users] WHERE reputation > 5` and I want to download the dataset. Any idea if it is feable to make it?

Comment: yes - if you have your own dataset. otherwise BigQuery tries create temporary table in public dataset - which obviously not going to work. do you actually have your own project in GCP?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I suppose yes. The name is project-201220. I created it after I pressed the first step "GO TO THE MANAGE RESOURCES PAGE" but I didn't make any other configuration

Comment: you might need to create your first (empty) dataset in this project. in BigQuery tables are created in datasets which in turn are created within the project

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I went to project -> create new dataset but I receive this message: 'Billing has not been enabled for this project. Enable billing at https://console.cloud.google.com/billing.' As I can understand in order to create the empty data in this project needs the paid version?

Comment: You should use Free Trial - https://cloud.google.com/free/

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion in the comments to your question, I see that you are getting started with the Google Cloud Platform, so let me provide some first-steps in order to get initialized in using BigQuery:

## GCP

The Google Cloud Platform offers a [Free Trial period](https://cloud.google.com/free/) (as explained by @Mikhail) of 12 months and $300 free credit to get started with the Platform. Moreover, there are some features and products which are always free. If we talk about BigQuery specifically, you can go to [this GCP Blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/05/try-google-bigquery-today-now-with-10gb-of-free-storage) where the Free tier for BigQuery is explained with more detail.

So, in order to begin with the Google Cloud Platform, you should start by [creating a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects). I presume you already have one (note that it is better not to share the Project ID of your GCP project, so whenever making a public question, please obfuscate it using `PROJECT_ID` or any other placeholder).

## BigQuery

Once you have your project, go the [**BigQuery UI**](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/) in the GCP Console, [create a dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets) (you should have [*bigquery.datasets.create* permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#required_permissions) for that) with which you will be working.

In your case, you are querying the [Stack Overflow public dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow), and you want to download the results from your query as CSV. To do so, you can follow the steps detailed in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#downloading_and_saving_query_results), also taking into account that there are some [limitations in this feature](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#limitations_1), such as: the results should be smaller than 16,000 rows and 10MB, and you cannot download nested/repeated data.

Given that I presume the query you are running returns more than 16,000 results, you should instead [write the results into a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#saving_query_results_to_a_table), using your project and dataset (which you created by following the steps I have explained earlier in this answer). To do so, you will need the *bigquery.tables.create* permissions, as stated in the error message that you obtained. Therefore, you will need that the Project owner of the project you are working with grants you [the right permissions or roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#required_permissions). This can be done through [the IAM page in the Console](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting_access_to_team_members).

Finally, once the query results are written in the table in your dataset, you can then export them using the [**Export functionality**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in_bigquery) without having to query the data again. For that, you will need a [**Cloud Storage bucket**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets), given that BigQuery exports only work with GCS.

Once the data is exported into your bucket, you can access it through the [Cloud Storage tab](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/) in the Console, go to your bucket and download the CSV files that were generated.

---

I know this might be a lot of data to process, so let me summarize the steps:

1. Create a GCP project (using the Free Trial period if you wish, or binding a Billing Account instead).
2. Create a BigQuery dataset in your project.
3. Query the Stack Overflow public dataset and export the results into a table in your dataset.
4. Create a Cloud Storage bucket in your project.
5. Export the table you created (containing the results of your query) to your bucket.
6. Download the content to your local environment, if you wish.